# Getting started with Java Checkers Engine

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, game-engine

I want to build a Checkers game engine in Java, most probably without a GUI if it is quicker. However I am having trouble getting started. Is there any starting point or advice to help get me started. Also how do I implement an AI using a brute force algorithm and an alpha beta pruning algorithm as I want to compare the two algorithms for an essay?

Thanks!

Comment: There are probably a lot of tutorials for that on the net. I'd suggest starting with the game itself being played by two humans. Then add in the AI.

Comment: The tutorials I have seen so far haven't been very helpful. Any chance you could link a few good ones?

Comment: I myself didn't use many tutorials of that kind so unfortunately I can't provide a good one. Besides that it probably also depends on your skills etc., i.e. not every "good" tutorial actually helps everybody. What's the problem with the tutorials you found so far? Where they incomplete? Did you have a hard time understanding them, especially the code? If so you might need to learn more basics first.

Comment: I've found one that works but there are some others which aren't helpful at all because all they do is show you the code with no comments and don't explain what they do at all. If you have worked AI, could you give an example of a brute force minimax algorithm or an idea of how to build it for this game?

Comment: Why not just implement a simple MinMax-algorithm from Wikipedias pseudocode. There are some implementation-details you need to think about first: (1) How to implement a move-generator (2) How to implement my data-structures needed for doing/undoing moves. (3) How to evaluate the board-state. Without algorithms for (1) & (3) you can't start. (2) is somehow domain-specific and the pure MinMax algorithm is the most simple thing regarding your tasks. Also check the [chessprogramming-wiki](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/), which has a lot of good material despite beeing a different game.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is read the description of alpha-beta pruning in Russel and Norvig's "Artificial Intelligence - A Modern Approach" and then look at the corresponding source code at https://github.com/aimacode/aima-java
(in directory /aima-core/src/main/java/aima/core/search/adversarial).